# Haskell Stack - how to disable copying executables during stack test?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

After invoking

```
stack new foo
stack build foo:test:foo-test --test --fast --no-copy-bins --no-copy-compiler-tool
```

Stack is still copying and installing library and executables:

> foo> copy/register Installing library in
> /tmp/foo/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/c2ce3190a19b85be796c6c0a3948129db378f9cd184b6b091f74bef68e262808/8.8.4/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.8.4/foo-0.1.0.0-JFvztN1xJpOHaq2zHLpyHS
> Installing executable foo-exe in
> /tmp/foo/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/c2ce3190a19b85be796c6c0a3948129db378f9cd184b6b091f74bef68e262808/8.8.4/bin
> Registering library for foo-0.1.0.0..

How can I disable copying of executables during `stack build --test`? I have a project with dozen of executables and copying of them takes longer than executing tests...

```
% stack --version
Version 2.5.1, Git revision d6ab861544918185236cf826cb2028abb266d6d5 x86_64 hpack-0.33.0
```

Comment: What's the problem? It stays inside .stack-work. no-copy-bins is to prevent stack from copying them into your $HOME or some other global location, which it doesn't do already.

Comment: the problem is that this copying is unnecessary and should be avoided in this case

Comment: I doubt that `stack` currently provides a way to skip updating these executables. You may want to bring this up on `stack`'s issue tracker.